# PDF with page flip in AIR for iOS application

Tags: ios, air

Building an AIR for iOS wrapper for a pdf file.

Is anyone aware of any actionscript AS3 framework that allows page flipping and -or embedding pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

There is no viable solution to displaying PDFs in Flash outside of using StageWebView in iOS (doesn't work on Android), which cannot be altered in any way from Flash. I spent a good month trying to figure out the best way to do this last year. The only solutions involve converting the PDF into a SWF (generally using the excellent SWFTools), not something that can be done on-device without completely slowing down the app, and displaying that SWF. If that is an option, there are a myriad of options available for page flipping animations. You could also take a look at FlexPaper, which is built specifically for displaying PDFs in "zine" format

Answer (score 0):

it works for Android, you just have to allow internet in the descriptor xml file

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-push-notifications.html